# Element-wise array maximum function in NumPy (more than two arrays)

Tags: python, numpy, max

I'm trying to return maximum values of multiple array in an element-wise comparison. For example:

```
A = array([0, 1, 2])
B = array([1, 0, 3])
C = array([3, 0, 4])
```

I want the resulting array to be `array([3,1,4])`.

I wanted to use `numpy.maximum`, but it is only good for two arrays. Is there a simple function for more than two arrays?

Answer (score 64):

With this setup:

```
>>> A = np.array([0,1,2])
>>> B = np.array([1,0,3])
>>> C = np.array([3,0,4])
```

You can either do:

```
>>> np.maximum.reduce([A,B,C])
array([3, 1, 4])
```

Or:

```
>>> np.vstack([A,B,C]).max(axis=0)
array([3, 1, 4])
```

I would go with the first option.

Comment: I would try to hold the data in a two-dimensional array right from the start, and then use the second option.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The axis argument calls `reduce` in the end, I don't understand why it matters.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `reduce`. It repeatedly applies a binary function to a list of values...

For A, B and C given in question...

```
np.maximum.reduce([A,B,C])

 array([3,1,4])
```

It first computes the `np.maximum` of A and B and then computes the `np.maximum` of (`np.maximum` of A and B) and C.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
np.column_stack([A, B, C]).max(axis=1)
```

The result is the same as the solutions from the other answers.

I use Pandas more heavily than NumPy so for me it's easier to think of 1D arrays as something similar to Pandas Series. The above would be equivalent to:

```
pd.concat([A, B, C], axis=1).max(axis=1)
```