# Dividing the image into a grid(say 3x3) and extracting pixel value of each grid region

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, pixel

Hi I am trying to process a set of images(say 5). I want each image to be considered as a layer which is divided into a 3x3 grid where each grid region represents a pixel. I want to get the maximum of pixel values from each layer(image) and produce a final image with maximum pixel values from each layer. Right now I have just tried to draw a grid on a single image but I don't think it is the correct approach. Any suggestions on how to get the desired solution.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
y_start= im1.height
y_end= 0
x= 100
for x in range(0,im1.width,50):
    line= ((x,y_start),(x,y_end))
    draw =ImageDraw.Draw(im1)
    draw.line(line,fill=('white'))
plt.imshow(im1)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
x_start= 0
x_end= im1.height

for y in range(0,im1.height,50):
    line= ((x_start,y),(x_end,y))
    draw =ImageDraw.Draw(im1)
    draw.line(line,fill=('white'))
plt.imshow(im1)

pix_val = list(im1.getdata())
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Let's take any pixel, say the centre one, and on each layer we find the maximum pixel in a 3x3 window around that central pixel, so now we have 5 pixels to put in the central location - how do we do that?

Comment: @MarkSetchell each layer corresponds to each individual image. So considering the center pixel we will have 5 values corresponding to the central position but we should consider the maximum of those 5 central points in the final matrix. I hope this clears it a bit.

Comment: Do you want to write this in Python, or do you just want to get the job done and move on? I ask because you can do it with ImageMagick in a shell one-liner without writing any code.

Comment: @MarkSetchell my preference is python but I would appreciate the help so that I can implement it in python

Answer (score 2):

I'll work on a Python solution afterwards, but you can get going with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

Just in Terminal, or (Command Prompt on Windows) you can get the maximum of a 3x3 area like this:

```
magick input.png -statistic maximum 3x3 result.png
```

Then if you load a sequence of images, you can get the maximum of all of the 3x3 windows in each like this, assuming your files are called `1.png`, `2.png` ...:

```
magick [12345].png -statistic maximum 3x3 -evaluate-sequence max result.png
```

If your files are named differently, you may have to enumerate them:

```
magick base_layer.png layer1.png important_layer.png ... statistic maximum 3x3 -evaluate-sequence max result.png
```

If you are using a v6 or older, ImageMagick, you'll need to use `convert` in place of `magick` in the foregoing commands.

---

With **OpenCV** you are going to need to call `cv2.dilate()` to get the maximum of a 3x3 window on each layer, then probably call `numpy.maximum.reduce()` to get the maximum across the resulting layers, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21816556/2836621).

The dilation looks like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Make 3x3 structuring element for dilation
kernel  = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)

im = cv2.imread('1.png')
dilated = cv2.dilate(im, kernel, iterations=1)
```

Comment: thanks. I'll give this a try and I'll be grateful if you come up with a Python solution. Meanwhile I'll try to implement it in Python myself.

Comment: I tried your solution but I don't want to dilate the existing image. It should divide the image into matrix and compare each block based on the pixel information inside the blocks. The block with more pixel information should be considered for the final image. I hope it clears what I am trying to do. Again I would like to thank you for your effort.

Comment: Did you try the ImageMagick command? There are Python bindings called **Wand** that'll work the same.