# Identify an array with the maximum value, element wise in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for a variation on the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816433/element-wise-array-maximum-function-in-numpy-more-than-two-arrays)

Given multiple arrays (3 or more), i need to construct a new array where each element identifies the input array which had the maximum value.

eg

```
array0 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
array1 = np.array([0, 3, 4])
array2 = np.array([-1, 1, 1])
```

the resulting array should be `array([0,1,1])`

np.maximum.reduce does not seem to work in the case.
I could only come up with a brute force for loop

```
d = []
for i in range(len(array0)):
  k = 0
  if array1[i] > array0[i]:
    k = 1
  if array2[i] > array1[i] and array2[i] > array0[i]:
    k = 2
  d.append(k)
```

Is there a more pythonic/numpy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a new array from the three and take the [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) along the first axis:

```
np.array([array0, array1, array2]).argmax(0)
# array([0, 1, 1])
```